# How to retrieve data that is sent by ajax in php?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am still a student and I am really new to web development. I am currently learning ajax. I wanted to pass (via button) an ID to my PHP script for SQL processing, and display the data retrieved to my page without reloading it. But it doesn't seem to work. After I press the button, it visually loads the PHP page (which, in my own understanding, wasn't suppose to happen when using ajax).

HTML and JavaScript code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

</head>
<body>

<?php
  session_start();
?>
<form action="retrieve_data.php" method="POST" name="searchForm">
    EMPLOYEE ID: <input type="text" name='emp_id' id='emp_id'/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" onsubmit="searchEmp()"/>
</form>
    <br>
    NAME:<p id="empName"></p><br>
    POSITION:<p id="empPos"></p>

 <script>

 function searchEmp() {

            var empID = document.getElementById('emp_id').value;
            var query = "?emp_id = " + empID;
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

           if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
              document.getElementById('empName').innerHTML = '<?php echo  $_SESSION["empName"]; ?>';
              document.getElementById('empPos').innerHTML = '<?php echo  $_SESSION["empPosition"];?>';

           }
        }

            xhr.open("GET", "retrieve_data.php" +query, true);

            xhr.send(null);

        };
    </script>
```

retrieve_data.php:

```
    <?php

session_start();
if(!empty($_GET["emp_id"])){

$_SESSION["emp_id"] = $_GET["emp_id"];
$emp_id = $_SESSION["emp_id"];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "overtimedtr";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM employees where id ='".$emp_id."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $_SESSION["empName"] = $row['name'];
        $_SESSION["empPosition"] = $row['position'];

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
}

?>
```

Here's a picture of my html page:

[image: A picture of my html page]

What I am trying to do is when I click the search button, the page should display the name and the position without reloading the page in a `<p>` element whose id's are "empName" and "empPos", the outcome isn't what i wanted, it displays my PHP page instead (which displays empty).

EDIT:

I have discovered that I don't need to add `method="GET"` in the form, then the page did not have to refresh, just as what I have wanted.

```
<form name="searchForm">
        EMPLOYEE ID: <input type="text" name='emp_id' id='emp_id'/>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" onsubmit="searchEmp()"/>
</form>
```

The only remaining problem is that I could not seem to get the value of `$_SESSION["empName"]` and `$_SESSION["empPosition"]` from my PHP page. What could I have been getting wrong?

```
if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
              document.getElementById('empName').innerHTML = '<?php echo  $_SESSION["empName"]; ?>';
              document.getElementById('empPos').innerHTML = '<?php echo  $_SESSION["empPosition"];?>';

           }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Comment: Do not session_start twice. it should be only once and in the start on file.

Comment: Please change `onClick` to `onSubmit` and add `event.preventDefault()` to stop the default action of the form .-

Comment: @Loek Nope, I was really hopeful that I'd find my answer, but was disappointed.

Comment: @GenesisTepait note that SO is a community that does its level best to answer every question we can. Still, we can't actually answer everything. If Dknacht's explanation isn't working for you, do some more research and edit your question. Good questions tend to get good answers.

Answer (score 1):

You have many errors in your code.

#### Errors in your retrieve_data.php

When you use AJAX, you **don't** use `$_SESSION` to exchange data; instead, you print the results like in a normal page but usually embeeded in a structured format like *JSON* or *XML*. What I recommend you is to organize everything that you are going to retrieve in an array and then use a coding function like `json_encode`.For example:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $result["empName"] = $row['name'];
        $result["empPosition"] = $row['position'];
    }
} else {
    $result["empName"] = '0 results.';
    $result["empPosition"] = '0 results.';
}
//json encode prints the result formatted
exit(json_encode($result));
```

#### Errors in your html

First of all, when you use AJAX, you *usually* **don't** use forms, because the default behaviour of a form is to load the page; also the info of method and action is already beeing given in the `open()` method so you are beeing redundant(Also notice that you are telling the form to use POST while AJAX to use GET). Better use a button. If you have to use use forms, then always return false to prevent the page being loaded.
Also, inside the `onreadystatechange` you must NOT use php's `echo`. Remember that PHP is a preprocesor and once in the client side everything printed is inalterable. You must to use the XMLHttpRequest properties responseText or responseXML. This properties **contain** the response received.
If you follow my recommendation of using `json_encode` in you php file, then tou need to use JSON.parse to process the data received.
Also in your query string **don't** use spaces
So for example:

```
EMPLOYEE ID: <input type="text" name='emp_id' id='emp_id'/>
<button onclick="searchEmp()">Search</button>
<br>
NAME:<p id="empName"></p><br>
POSITION:<p id="empPos"></p>

<script>

    function searchEmp() {
        var empID = document.getElementById('emp_id').value;
        var query = "?emp_id=" + empID;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                document.getElementById('empName').innerHTML = jsonResponse.empName;
                document.getElementById('empPos').innerHTML = jsonResponse.empPosition;
            }
        }

        xhr.open("GET", "retrieve_data.php" + query, true);
        xhr.send(null);
    }
</script>
```

I recommend you to check basic AJAX documentation, because it seems that you have some confusion in some AJAX concepts.

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: I just have discovered that my `if(xhr.readyState == 4)` does not even execute. Why? Is there any particular requirement for it to execute? I know that "4" is a numeric code which means "after the request has been completed, and the response data has been completely received from the server" but I guess it does not do that, am I missing anything?

Comment: Still the same. I have added an `alert(""+xhr.readystate)` below `xhr.send()`, it says 1. How is this making sense

Comment: No, you have a confusion. After the send() call, the script will finish. Then, when a change in the request occurs, JavaScript will call the onreadystatechange method asynchronously. If you put an alert() inside onreadystatechange (let's say, before `if (xhr.readyState == 4) {`) you will notice that this will be excecuted 4 times. I suggest that you put an alert(this.readyState) to see what you get.

Comment: I put an `alert(this.readyState)` before `(xhr.readyState == 4)` and it alerted 4 times with 1 as first alert, then 2,3 , and by the last time it was executed, my alert says 4. This confused me even more lol

Comment: That means all from the ajax request is Ok. Now, after `if (xhr.readyState == 4) {` put `alert(this.responseText)` and tell me what it shows. Probably you have some syntax error in your PHP so the JSON does not get back clear (is returned with some warning that does not allow to parse it properly)

Comment: Am I wrong to think that my PHP is not the case? because I have changed my `document.getElementById('empName').innerHTML = jsonResponse.empName;
                document.getElementById('empPos').innerHTML = jsonResponse.empPosition;` to `document.getElementById("empName").innerHTML = "NICE!"
      document.getElementById("empPos").innerHTML = "NICE!"` and it still doesn't work, this is what actually confused me.

Comment: quit the first two lines above and see if it works. I mean just leave document.getElementById("empName").innerHTML = "NICE!" document.getElementById("empPos").innerHTML = "NICE!" and let's see if it still wont work